# Tikz beginner question: Align to center of symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to align the centers of the symbols `\Circle`, `\CIRCLE`, `\times`, not the centers of the nodes. Is there a simple way?

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
  \matrix (m) [
    matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=1.5em, minimum height=4em, %nodes in empty cells , minimum width=3em
    nodes={anchor=center}
    ]
  {
   \CIRCLE^{\frac{1}{4}} & \Circle^{\frac{1}{4}} & (\Circle^{\frac{1}{4}}\CIRCLE^{\frac{1}{4}}) & \bm{\times} \\
  };
\path
(m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
(m-1-3) edge (m-1-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\smash{^{\frac{1}{4}}}` for all the superscripts, then they won't take up any vertical space and hence won't affect the alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,t]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
  \matrix (m) [
    matrix of math nodes, row sep=3em, column sep=1.5em, minimum height=4em, %nodes in empty cells , minimum width=3em
    nodes={anchor=center}
    ]
  {
   \CIRCLE\smash{^{\frac{1}{4}}} & \Circle\smash{^{\frac{1}{4}}} & (\Circle\smash{^{\frac{1}{4}}}\CIRCLE\smash{^{\frac{1}{4}}}) & \bm{\times} \\
  };
\path
(m-1-1) edge (m-1-2)
(m-1-2) edge (m-1-3)
(m-1-3) edge (m-1-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it also work if I connect the nodes vertically? – Cesare 36 mins ago

Comment: @Cesare No (which you will have seen if you tried), `\smash` only changes the vertical extent, the horizontal extent remains the same. For that case you could use `\rlap{$^{\frac{1}{4}}$}`